# Micro Front end Single SPA - died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: Error loading

Tags: single-spa, single-spa-angular

single-spa-layout.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: application 'app' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: Error loading

Root application running on one server , and Sub application running on  another server.
On accessing root sub application main.js file not loading. showing above error.

Access to script at 'https://external.com/Common/main.js' from origin 'https://test.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How to fix this issue.

Comment: Hello.  What you provide is insufficient to receive help.  Usually, an error message and stack trace follows the error message you show.  What are you seeing?

Comment: Hi @JoséRamírez Issue is accessing main.js file from Root. Its showing CORS error.

We added Access Control in Root application.
webpack.config.js 

{
      devServer: {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization'
        },
        allowedHosts: 'all',
      },
    }

Comment: Ok, so maybe your CORS header is not correct.  At this point I can tell you that this is not a single-spa issue.  Work this out for whichever HTTP server you are using to serve the application.